# MyBatis select query with IN but without forEach

Tags: mybatis

how can I use a select query where I have only two values for one column without using for each loop ?

Comment: for example SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 IN ('value1', 'value2');
corresponding Mybatis
 <iterate open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">
   #[]#
  </iterate>
OR BY USING for each , is there any other way we can achieve functionality of 'IN' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using `IN`, you can use `OR`:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE co1 = `value1` OR col1 = `value2`
```

Comment: when I am using 'or' its not fetching the result same as that of "IN"  and I cant use "for each" or "iterator" because its not a list

Comment: thanks , it worked had to work arround with brackets ^.^ , thanks again

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR('VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3','[^,]+',1 LEVEL)) VAL
  FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY INSTR('VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3', ',', 1, LEVEL-1) > 0
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: I don't see any relationship with the question here.